# Skip zero from number attribute value

Tags: html

I need to set -1 as min and max to 10 in number HTML field. from this I need to skip 0.that is I don't need to submit its value as 0. is this possible in HTML?

```
 <input type="number" min="-1" max="10"> //I need something like skip = 0
```

Comment: You need to use Javascript.  You could use document.`Math.abs(getElementByID('number').value) !== 0` on your input assuming you give it an `id='number'`.

Comment: try dropdown , easy to use with preset restrictions

Comment: in `onchange` event, when it is 0, switch it to -1 or 1 as desired

Comment: @Sablefoste I agree with your solution. but is there a way to do it in html.because I stuck in that way to use only in html.

Comment: Why is there a label for PHP then?

Comment: I agree that you should use JS for this. The number input type doesn't give you attributes to prevent an input within the range of min and max.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is rather simple on this one.

It's not possible with plain html, since there is no `skip=""` and `pattern=""` doesn't work on number inputs. You have to use a Javascript function.

Comment: Yes i did. but OP's goal was: 'I need to set -1 as min and max to 10 in number HTML field'. Which is simply not possible. Splash changed the input type to 'text'.

Comment: @luissimo try to insert -2 or 11 in demo link

Comment: I'm not saying it doesn't work, cause obviously it does and i don't think there is better solution with plain HTML, but it's simply not what OP asked for.

Comment: I don't see where the OP said it had to be a number input.  His system should clearly validate *any* data sent back to it, and use `isNumeric` to confirm the data (he originally tagged it PHP).

Answer (score 4):

You can add pattern attribute and change type to 'text'

```
<input type="text"  pattern="[1-9]|10|-1">
```

[demo](https://jsfiddle.net/ntkLa3y4/1)

Comment: For some reason it does not work in Chrome for me. Zero is still there.

Comment: it would not give arrow keys usability.

Comment: Per MDN: **This attribute applies when the value of the type attribute is text, search, tel, url, email or password; otherwise it is ignored.** This will not work for a `type="number"`

Comment: But what OP lost with changing type of input. It will be correct numeric string in result

Comment: And in any case, I don't think that it's reason for downvoting

Answer (score 1):

Add this javascript to your page...
I have created a function and called that function to  your input  `onchange="return check_value();"`. Also added `id="number"`
Include a jquery.js file for the script to work...
Here the script checks your input value and if its '0' it alerts the user that zero is not allowed and clears the value in the input field.... Try and let me know....

```
 <input type="number" id="number" min="-1" max="10" onchange="return check_value();">
    <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function check_value(){  
            //get the number
            var number = $('#number').val();  

                    if(number == 0){  
                        //show that the number is not allowed  
                        alert("0 value Not Allowed!"); 
                        $("#number").val('');
                    }
    }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [Step attribute](http://www.wufoo.com/html5/attributes/04-minmaxstep.html)

That will be the only html fix I think but its not a good solution ;(

```
<input type="number" min="-1" max="10" step="2">
```

Comment: but it will not skip 0 alone. it will skip every thing to 2. I need to skip only 0